# Cancelling Emirates flex plus flight

Tags: bookings, tips-and-tricks, cancellations, refunds, emirates

I recently bought an in and outbound ticket from Emirates. Flying from Lyon-Dubai-Johannesburg and back on the same route. The outbound journey is an "economy flex" fare and the inbound journey is "economy flex plus." At the time when I bought it, I suspected I might have to cancel the inbound journey, and therefore I chose flex plus, as it offered cancellations free of charge, where the economy flex fare charges 150euro.

My question now is, do I cancel the inbound/flex plus/JHB-DUB-LYON before utilizing the outbound flight or after or does it not make any difference with regards to the refund?

I read through the terms and conditions, but struggling to make sense of it.

Comment: What did Emirates say when you called them?

Comment: Did you buy two separate tickets? If yes, then what's the problem?

Comment: @chx It's one ticket by the sound of the question

Answer (score 1):

Its one ticket. Phoned them and it seems my best option is to either cancel it and rebook a one way ticket or to use the outbound flight and then cancel the inbound, but will pay a refund penalty of 150euro and something else if I cancel only the inbound ticket now.